# Mysql run stored procedure after server restart

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I run a stored procedure at server start-up? Is this possible?
I just want to run a SQL query.

Comment: Please elaborate, this does not make sense to me...

Comment: @Dennis It makes perfect sense! Here's the MSSQL equivalent: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/08/14/60280.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the init-file variable in your configuration file to run a text file containing SQL statements in it.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer with a link to documentation and/or an example?

Comment: @Dennis, would you be able to provide a code example?